# Multiple users roles loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I am trying to make an application using Loopback as my back-end. I already used loopback before, but right now I want to do something that I never done before.

What I want is simple, I will have 3 types of users, administrator, servicer and default. But, I need to restrict the access controls for each type of user; the administrator can request all my routes, but de default user for example can only request some routes that I will specify. The ACL part I know how to do, but I can't find anything explaining how to make each type of user a role and make it work.

Anyone can post here an example with at least two users and roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to persist the 2 new roles into your database, "administrator" and "servicer". You can either do this step manually or create a script you can reuse:

```js
// commands/add_roles.js

let app = require('../server/server')

function createRole(name, description, done) {
  app.models.Role.findOrCreate(
    {where: {name: name}}, 
    {name, description},
    err => {
      // TODO handle error
      
      done && done()
    }
  )  
}

createRole('administrator', 'Administrators have more control on the data', () => {
  createRole('servicer', 'servicer description', process.exit)
})
```

Then, you associate a role to a user. Execute the code below whenever you desire, depending on your application.

```js
app.models.Role.findOne({where: {name: 'administrator'}}, (err, role) => {
  // TODO handle error

  app.models.RoleMapping.findOrCreate({where: {principalId: user.id}}, {
    roleId: role.id,
    principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
    principalId: user.id
  }, function (err) {
    // TODO handle error
      
    // if no errors, user has now the role administrator
  })
})
```

You can now use the roles "administrator" and "servicer" in your models' ACLs.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for and pretty simple example, thank you so much