# creating a superuser admin in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, acl

Am still digging deep into loopback kindly help out. I have the following models: `admin`=> extends the built-in `User` model, `student`=> extend from the built in `User` model and other models ofcoz.

Brief:

I do not want an authenticated instance `student` to be able to to access the endpoint `Student GET /students`. I do not want `Student` to be able to have access to information about all of the `Student`(s). So, I've proposed admin, which should be able to access the endpoint  GET /students through the implementation of a Role. I want the admin to be able to access all endpoints

Standing:

In script.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
 const User = app.models.admin;
 const Role = app.models.Role;
 const RoleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;


 Role.find({ name: 'admin' }, function(err, results) {
    if (err) { 
        throw err;
     }

    if (results.length < 1) {

        // now  Role creation...
   User.create([{name:'Felix Olonde',username:"felix",email: 'felix@gmail.com', password: 'felix123',phone_number:3127287656,dob:1988-03-04,state: 'LA'
    }
  ], function(err, users) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('Created user:', users);

    //create the admin role
    Role.create({
      name: 'admin'
    }, function(err, role) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log('Created role:', role);

      role.principals.create({
        principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
        principalId: users[0].id
      }, function(err, principal) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log('Created principal:', principal);
      });
    });
  });

    }
});

}
```

student.json

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",//student to access their own information
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "find"
    }
  ],
```

admin.json

```
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
```

Problem

After logging in the admin which is successfully created in the database( I use mongo hosted in mLab), when i try to get all students using the explorer i keep getting 401.."Authorization Required"

Aim

I only want admin to be able to really have complete control over the  API endpoints. I.e. admin should be able to get all students etc.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, a good design is having a single class Member (or Customer or whatever you like) extending the built-in User model.

Basically, you register two members, create the role admin and promote admin one of the two members. An example here: 
[Multiple users roles loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697014/multiple-users-roles-loopback/51740651#51740651)

The acls in `student.json` is correct and will work.

If you really want to have different models extending the built-in User, access control with multiple user models is well explained in the official documentation:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Authentication-authorization-and-permissions.html#access-control-with-multiple-user-models

Comment: The issue is that when I log in the admin and set its access Token, I am not able to get the students. I get 401-Authorization required...

Comment: Read the links I posted and fix your app accordingly. If you wanna have two different models for your users, then you've to implement two different access token models.