# How to create a Role in Loopback/Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, admin, loopbackjs, roles

I created this method to create an Admin Role.
I have to check in user table if the admin field is set to 0 or 1 of the current user to detect if it's a normal user or an admin.
Problem is when I  `console.log('obj',objUser)` I get this :

```
obj Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

This is what I've built so far :

```
Role.registerResolver('Admin', function(role, context, cb) {

            //Q: Is the user logged in? (there will be an accessToken with an ID if so)
            var userId = context.accessToken.userId;

            if (!userId) {
              //A: No, user is NOT logged in: callback with FALSE
              return process.nextTick(() => cb(null, false));
            }

            var user = app.models.user;

            var objUser = user.findById(userId);
            console.log('obj',objUser)
            if(objUser.admin==1){
              return cb(null, true);
            }
            else{
              return cb(null, false);
            }

            });
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong am I doing. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697014/multiple-users-roles-loopback/51740651#51740651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read about javascript [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises), it's crucial to understand javascript in general and async programming. Also, check the [async/await](https://alligator.io/js/async-functions/)